# Which react-native version support all npms?

Tags: react-native

Whenever I update react -native , one or other npm show following messages (image):[image]

Comment: Try deleting node_modules folder and do 'npm install'.

Comment: Images of text are not searchable, and they are extremely hard to read on smaller screen sizes like phone screens. Please [edit] the question and paste the error message as text into the question.

Comment: @HungrySoul I tried doing that , but was unsuccessful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It went after closing terminal
deleting node modules and installing everything successfully